# Creating a new Bitmap starting from an old one?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

For example: I have a bitmap 20x20, then I do some calculation and I need a new bitmap 30x30 with inside the old one for example in the center of the new bitmap. Is there a way to do that?

I'm creating an image dynamically using a canvas=canvas(mybitmap) but my image has no fixed dimensions. For example, I want to draw a path of a man into space. I create dynamically the image so that, if the man goesto east direction I will have a bitmap that grows in orizontal dimension (1x1 1x2 1x3....) andso on. if he turns to the north direction the bitmap must grow in vertical dimension (1x5 2x5 3x5).

I want not to redraw all the image but copy the old one into the new extended one and add only the new "data".

(I can't draw always on the same image because maybe I have to translate all the image and add some "space" in the first column or the first row of the bitmap")

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a matrix to resize the bitmap?

If you can't just resize the one bitmap, why not still use a matrix then drawBitmap to your canvas(Bitmap) if you really need it done like that...

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/resizing-a-bitmap/